# Core dump when running C program using systemd

Tags: c, daemon, systemd

I have a program in C that runs well when running it directly from the comand line but fails when running it with systemd:

```
Core was generated by `/usr/local/bin/midnite-modbusd'.
Program terminated with signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception.
#0  0x0000000000401308 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7ffeae390268) at src/midnite-modbusd.c:139
139                     slen= interval - (millis % interval);
```

The code in question:

```
//wait for start of each sample interval
gettimeofday(&tv,NULL);
millis= (long long unsigned)tv.tv_sec*1000 + (tv.tv_usec/1000);
slen= interval - (millis % interval);
i= (millis+slen) % 1000;
usleep (slen*1000);
```

The full code [is available on github](https://github.com/loxK/midnite-modbusd/blob/master/src/midnite-modbusd.c#L139).

The systyemd unit:

```
[Unit]
Description=Midnite Classic modbus data polling
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=midnite-modbusd
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/midnite-modbusd
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

What can be so different when a program runs with systemd ?

## Edit 1

It seems that my program has major issues that only happen when running with systemd:

- it won't read my configuration file, which should throw an error message and `exit(1)` [because of invalid values](https://github.com/loxK/midnite-modbusd/blob/master/src/midnite-modbusd.c#L250)
- journactl doesn't get filled in real time. Using `journactl -f` I have to wait a couple of minutes before seeing a bunch of logs that appear suddenly

As a side note for my tests using the command line I run: `sudo -H -u midnite-modbusd /usr/local/bin/midnite-modbusd`

Comment: Do you initialize `interval`?

Comment: @GauravSehgal He does not if it's not provided as a parameter. So perhaps this is the problem? Perhaps `systemd` doesn't provide command line arguments( at least in this example).

Comment: As a global at the beginning of the script: int  interval;         //sample interval

Comment: @Laurent initialize as in set it to known value, not declare it.

Comment: The same binary runs properly from the command line without a single argument.

Comment: @orhtej2 the interval value is retrieved from the config file before running the loop.

Comment: Divide by zero?

Comment: Well I gave interval a default value and it runs, I am currently investigating why is that...

Comment: You're dividing by interval. When interval is 0, you get a division by zero error (sigfpe). Make sure interval is never 0.

Comment: @rustyx Indeed. I am still investigate as of why it does when running with systemd whereas that never happens when running it directly.

Comment: @Laurent perhaps because of your compiler optimizations. Try compiling with something equivalent to `-O0` and you might see the error in the program too. What I mean is that the compiler might be removing undefined behavior at a higher optimization level.

Comment: The only reason I can figure out to explain why it works on console but not in systemd  is permissions

Comment: @JoseFelipe More likely a difference in signal handlers when run under systemd.

Comment: @AndrewHenle definitely yours sounds better

Comment: Learn to debug `core` dumps [with `gdb`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/)

Comment: Why has it been down voted ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue in this code:

```
if (getppid()==1) {
    sprintf(str, "Daemon aready running");
    log_message(log_file_path,(char*)str);
    return;
}
```

This code is here for when the program was intended to fork itself to run as an "old style" daemon. 
I didn't realize that, as systemd is forking it, then the program have a parent process (thus `getppid()` returning `1` when running with systemd but not from the command line)

Anyway it is badly written: this test should stop the script.

Answer (score 1):

A defined value of *sample_interval* from configuration file will initialize the *interval*, please check if the file is correct and *sample_interval* is present. An uninitialized value of *interval* might cause the divide by zero exception

Comment: It is, I can run `sudo -H -u midnite-modbusd /usr/local/bin/midnite-modbusd` without an issue. But when it comes to running the exact same command from systemd it crashes.

Comment: @vnay-p please see my edit on the question, when running with systemd the program doesn't seem to read the configuration file.